# How do I post an Open Graph action to a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

With timelines rolling out to Fan and Business pages, I would like to be able to publish actions to our Business page timeline. I can't figure out how to do that. Any guidance?

When I try to post to the page (with an unapproved og action), I get:

{"error":{"message":"(#100) The Action Type ACTION_TYPE is not approved, so app APP_NAME_SPACE can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app. User PAGE_ID is not one of those roles.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}

Comment: I guess the only way to find out is to get your actions approved.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post an OG action to a page

> Actions are defined through the App Dashboard. Once an application has defined the types of actions that it publishes, the application can invoke the Graph API to publish action instances to Open Graph -- this connects the current **user** with an appropriate object instance via the action
>
> <sub>-- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/</sub>

[image: How actions work]

There is no documentation on saying it's *not* possible because documentation usually shows *what is* possible. Listing all the negatives of a feature isn't something I think Facebook does.

Comment: I guess there are a lot of developers preferring to check things out practically when there is no point in the documentation saying that what they try to achieve is not possible. Sometimes it's worth the effort.

Comment: Besides - have you ever seen a complete documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share how far I came:

1. got actions approved by Facebook.
2. published actions to page with user access token => works accept that the actions do not appear on the timeline of the page, they appear on the user's timeline instead.
3. fetched page access token (scope: publish_actions, manage_pages) and published actions to page with page access token => failed with "An unknown error has occurred." of type: "OAuthException".

My conclusion: It's not possible.

Comment: For the _xth_ time, __of course__ it is __not__ possible to publish an action as a page, because OG actions are supposed to be undertaken by __real__ people …

Comment: @CBroe Read the question carefully: It does not say that we want to publish the action as a page. We just want the action to appear on a page. Be careful with 'of course'. Posting to a page as a page or as an admin of a page is possible via graph api, so why shouldn't it be possible to publish actions as a page or as a page admin on a page? 'xth time'? Guide us to the particular lines in the documentation please.

Comment: The error changed. I'm getting "OAuthException: (#10) App is not allowed to publish actions for pages". I have both manage_pages and publish_actions permissions granted on my app.

Comment: Did you ever get past this? I am getting the same behaviour you describe, with my action showing up on the user timeline instead of on the page timeline

Comment: @RuyDiaz no, never did, sry.

Comment: I've created an issue on Facebook support: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/361360557292714

Answer (score 0):

Actually I came up with a work-around solution which might be useful for you, but you have to have a Twitter account..

- First, you need to create a Twitter account if you do not have one.
- Then, you need to connect your twitter account with your facebook
     profile or any page admin profile (Twitter -> Settings -> Apps). And check `post to my Facebook page:` and select your page.
- Using the twitter `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` of the Twitter account, you can tweet the post you want.
- The post will be automatically posted on your Facebook page

Of course there are some drawbacks, like having the twitter account, and the links will appear on your Facebook page shorten via Twitter [`http://t.co/`], but I think it is the only solution.