# Post Open Graph Action using the App Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post an action using Facebook Open Graph API based on the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#appanduserobjects). When I do the following :

```
curl -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/app/myNamespace:myAction"  \
  -F "access_token=$APP_TOKEN" \
  -F "myObject=https://myhost.com/objectid"
```

I get the following error :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

I have obtained a valid 'App Token' using this [Faceboo documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/). The document states that actions can be published using App Tokens.

Btw, I am able to successfully post actions using user-access-token as follows :

```
curl -X POST \
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/myNamespace:myAction' \
-F 'myObject=https://myhost.com/' \
-F 'access_token=user-access-token'
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As messick already said, you can not publish actions "as" an app - actions are meant to be undertaken by real people. You can however _use_ your app token to publish an action for a user - but you need to have their `publish_actions` permission, and you have to use their user id to post against (`/me` does only work with a user access token, otherwise the API can't know who "me" is supposed to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to post to an Open Graph action as the app, which is not possible.

Unfortunately, there is no documentation to that explictly says this, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528725/how-do-i-post-an-open-graph-action-to-a-facebook-page) is someone who tried to do the same thing.

If you read the documentation you posted, you'll see two main points. First, app tokens are for publishing information on the feeds of user's who have given permission to the app to do so, and app tokens are for some other basic "maintenance" type stuff for the app itself.  There is nothing in there that support the idea that app tokens can be used for anything like posting regular Open Graph actions.